# Virtual Box Multimonitor Mouse issues

Tags: virtualbox

My mouse is exhibiting strange behavior in Virtualbox. It randomly exits the virtual pc and jumps to (0,0) on my primary monitor. Is there anyway to stop this?

**[EDIT]**

I determined it wasn't synergy's fault but something weird happening with my multi-monitor setup. The mouse only seems to work correctly on my primary monitor.

Comment: Oh I'm running Windows 7 64bit

Comment: Out of curiosity, by (0,0) do you mean the upper left corner (like Java), or the center of the screen (like math)? And what OS is on the VM?

Comment: yea (0,0) means upper left and OS is xp

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested?

Comment: Have not had a chance. Dont use Virtual Box all that often. Also consider today is the 1 year anniversary of this question!

Answer (score 2):

I at least found [this page](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/8047), which I believe describes the problem you are talking about. Apparently it is not new.. Does this only happen to you when you move towards the bottom of the screen?

I believe [this](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/2762) could fix your problem, which basically says to try [disabling 'Mouse Integration'](https://superuser.com/questions/214414/how-to-permanently-disable-mouse-integration-in-virtualbox).

Comment: @Kurru Did this work by any chance?